# Order of group of units of ${\bf Z}_{2015}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I know that the order of the group of units $U({\bf Z}_{2015})$ is 1440 and so the order of the group of units of the polynomial ring ${\bf Z}_{2015}[X]$ must be at least that because we can view each unit from the former group as a constant polynomial.

I have been lead to believe that the order of the polynomial ring above is also 1440. Is this true and if so, why?

Finally, how do I figure out if  $U({\bf Z}_{2015}[X])$ is cyclic without going through all of its elements to see if there is one with order 1440 (or other if this is not the group's order)?

Comment: [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure) for when $\,U(\Bbb Z_n)$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195226/242) that a polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ is a unit iff $\,f(0)\,$ is a unit and all other coefficients are nilpotent. But $\,2015 = 5\cdot 13\cdot 31 \,$ is a product of distinct primes, so there are no nontrivial niltpotents mod $2015$ since $\,p_i\mid a^n\,\Rightarrow\,p_i\mid a\,\Rightarrow\prod p_i \mid a\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv 0$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've changed the final question about being cyclic: I meant to enquire about the polynomial ring $U({\bf Z}_{2015}[X])$, not just $U({\bf Z}_{2015})$

Comment: @Jade What do you know about the relationship between the two unit groups from the above?

Comment: Does $U({\bf Z}_{2015})$ not being cyclic imply that the corresponding polynomial ring can't be either?

Comment: @Jade The answer implies that the units of this polynomial ring are precisely the units of its coefficient ring. So how are the unit groups related?

Comment: So elements of $U({\bf Z}_{2015})$ are the relatively prime congruence classes and the units of the polynomial ring exactly are the same ones. I have to admit I'm struggling to come up with what you're hinting at...

Comment: @Jade Yes, the unit groups are equal. Units remain units in any extension ring, and the above shows that there are no other units in this extension.

Comment: Right. Does the fact that there's no element in $U({\bf Z}_{2015})$ which generates that group mean that there isn't one to generate all of the units in the poly. ring and so it isn't cyclic either?

Comment: The groups are equal (or isomorphic, depending on how on constructs polynomial rings; cyclicity [is preserved](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/997636/242) by an isomorphism - think about it).